# Can we check the NSNotification table?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2

For example, say I want to see what's the actual current table of NSNotification. I want to see how it change after I add notification, after I remove observers, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you can't, at least without some runtime voodoo.

Comment: That means there is no easy way. Which is kind of sucks for programming.